# Free syntax highlighting component in .NET

Tags: .net, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone knows about good free syntax highlighting component for .NET?

Thanks a lot,
Adi Barda

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you looking to write an app that supports syntax highlighting? If so, is it wpf/winforms/console-based?

Comment: What language are you interested in web wpf windows what???

Answer (score 5):

We have used [CSharpEdit's](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpedit/) editor component. It takes a bit of work but is worth it.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/) version.
2. [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx).
3. [Learn about code highlighting techniques](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/RTBClass.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

- For open source options, check out ICSharpCode.TextEditor (a text editing component used inside Resharper). It supports configurable highlighting like [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/19/Smarter-Syntax-Highlighting.aspx) and [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/20/Custom-Syntax-Highlighting.aspx)
- For commercial options, try [Actipro's SyntaxEditor control](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx), they have both WinForms and WPF version
- If you want to add custom language support to Visual Studio, take a look at [language services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb985513.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an editor, Visual Studio Express (http://www.microsoft.com/express/) has syntax highlighting along with a ton of other features.

Comment: he voted -1 for both of us, he doesn't clarify the question then votes down for everybody

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion has such a component as part of the Winforms control. It is called EditControl. It can be used for free in many cases. Check the licensing for accurate details.